# Scan drive for files > 10GB and (if not already done) create tar split into 10GB chunks for each

Tags: shell, tar, split

I need to overcome a limitation of Amazon Cloud drive via the Cloud Sync app on my Synology NAS. This only allows files up to 10GB max to be sync to Amazon. I have a number of bluray rips which are larger.

I have already created a simple script to identify all such files but now for each such file I need to apply the logic as per the title of my question i.e.

for each matching file
  if there is no existing tar for the file
    create a tar, split into 10GB chunks (in the same folder)
  else
    do nothing

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a `tar` from a `mymovie.br` and have it in chunks of 10GB each, you can use this command:

`tar cvzf - mymovie.br | split --bytes=10GB - mymovie.tar.`

Basically all it's doing is taking your big file and `tar`ing it - then it `split`s it into 10GB chunks afterwards, which can be reassembled.